# Using ONLY Authorize.Net: Making Multiple Partial Captures on a Single Credit Card Charge Authorization

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, credit-card, authorize.net, payment-processing

I had a question regarding a similar question posed before (the thread titled "multiple captures on a single credit card authorization").

Essentially I ask the same question but would like to ask in detail if multiple partial captures are possible through Authorize.Net (I've checked their resources and found no conclusive answer).

The reason I ask this question is for this hypothetical situation. Suppose a customer orders item A and B. Item A is in stock and can be shipped right away but item B is not and needs to be obtained before it can be shipped. The customer would make a total payment combining the price for these two items in one single authorization, but as the seller, the seller would want to make two partial captures. One partial capture (and settlement) for item A as soon as it gets shipped, and a second partial capture (and settlement) at a later time when item B becomes available and gets shipped.

A user posted in the thread of the previous question that different processors can enable the ability for multiple partial captures (with a list of the processors), but I'm interested only in finding this capability in Authorize.Net.

Is there anyone out there who can give me a solid answer whether Authorize.Net supports this capability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do **not**. This is not something a payment gateway can support as they only handle the sending of the payment request to the processing bank and returning the response. US merchant accounts do not allow for an authorization code to be used more than once so it is there that you find your limitation. If you want to capture more payments from one card you should either request multiple authorization codes (which is a bad user experience as all of those funds are held until you release them) or don't use authorizations at all and charge the users in realtime but creating payment account using their CIM API and charging against them as necessary.

The processors who do support something like this are probably third party payment providers who have more flexibility in how their services are offered.

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not, but they probably will in the future. Technically, it's more complex to manage compliance than what you describe; for example authorization and settlement amount need to match, estimated authorization indicator, etc. See Visa Stored Credential Transaction Framework for more info. https://usa.visa.com/support/merchant/library/visa-merchant-business-news-digest.html Other payment gateway supports today.